# Redirect apache /whatever to /en/whatever

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my user from mysite.com/mobiles to mysite.com/en/mobiles if en is not present :

I tried this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}{3} !^/en$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's giving me an infinite loop..
Is the first line good ? Can i compare only 3 first caractere of request uri ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}{3} !^/en$ [NC]
```

The `%{REQUEST_URI}{3}` variable is invalid. You can't mix in regular expressions on the right side of the comparison (which wants to be a variable and/or literal). You want the regular expression on the left side to just check that it doesn't start with `/en/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
```